# Trying to make a query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, if-statement

I know that this query can have flaws but can you tell me how make it better. It is giving me error. I am a beginner so please dont be rude.

The query is :

```
SET @start = 0;

IF @start <= 45 
                   (SELECT 
                   groups.id AS groupid, 
                   count(papers.classes) AS cl, 
                   start + cl AS st 
               FROM groups,
                    gpaper,
                    papers 
               WHERE cid = '1'
                   AND sid = '4'
                   AND groups.id = '14'
                   AND gpaper.gid = groups.id
                   AND gpaper.pid = papers.paperid 
              ORDER BY groupname) AS t
```

I want result from the query until st is equal to cl.

The error am getting is this:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @start <= 45 
>                      (SELECT 
>                      groups.id AS g' at line 1

Comment: What is the error? It would be easier to know what we have to fix, or what to explain.

Comment: `I want result from the query until st is equal to cl. I know cl is not defined`. How do you equate something which is undefined with another? I think it would be better if you could show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: It will be a php variable. Sorry Let me correct it.

Comment: Without seeing proper DDLs and the desired result, it's pretty hard to help.

Comment: Syntax wise if you remove `(` at start and `) As t` it might work. But logically you should be using table `Join` rather than From table1, table2 which is old school syntax with a performance hit.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The error is this. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @start <= 45 
                   (SELECT 
                   groups.id AS g' at line 1

Comment: Do you want to create a stored procedure in your MySQL database, or do you want to use this on a front-end, like PHP? Notice that, although the logic may be similar, the implementation might differ (there are different advantages to one and the other).

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
IF (whatever = whatever) THEN /*<- then!*/
SELECT whatever FROM whatever; /*no parantheses and no alias*/
END IF;
```

Also note, that you can not use this if then thing in a simple query, you have to use it in a stored procedure or a function.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to just want to do the same query 46 times, with the only difference being whether you add 0, 1,...., 45 to a field.

If so it can probably be done with a single SELECT:-

```
SELECT Sub1.groupid, Sub1.cl, Sub1.cl + Sub0.iCnt AS st
FROM
(
    SELECT units.i + tens.i * 10 AS iCnt
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
    HAVING iCnt BETWEEN 0 AND 45
) Sub0
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT groups.id AS groupid, count(papers.classes) AS cl
    FROM groups
    INNER JOIN gpaper ON gpaper.gid = groups.id
    INNER JOIN papers ON gpaper.pid = papers.paperid 
    WHERE cid = '1'
    AND sid = '4'
    AND groups.id = '14'
) Sub1
ORDER BY Sub0.iCnt, groupname
```